# View gets loaded on wrong url

Tags: laravel

I have a PostsController that's supposed to show page for Image Upload, but it gets loaded under http://127.0.0.1:8000/p enpoint, instead of http://127.0.0.1:8000/p/create endpoint.

PostsController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use function Symfony\Component\String\b;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function create() {
        return view('posts.create');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        dd(request()->all());
    }

}
```

Routes:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/p/create', [App\Http\Controllers\PostsController::class, 'create']);
Route::post('/p', [App\Http\Controllers\PostsController::class, 'store']);

Route::get('/profile/{user}', [App\Http\Controllers\ProfilesController::class, 'index'])->name('profile.show');
```

create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <form action="/p" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      @csrf

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8 offset-2">

            <div class="row">
                <h1>Add New Post</h1>
            </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="caption" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">{{ __('Post Caption') }}</label>

                    
                        <input id="caption" 
                            type="text" 
                            class="form-control @error('caption') is-invalid @enderror" 
                            name="caption" 
                            value="{{ old('caption') }}">

                        @error('caption')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                        @enderror

                        <div class="row">
                            <label for="image" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">{{ __('Post Image') }}</label>
                            
                            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image">

                            @error('image')
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            @enderror

                            <div class="row pt-4">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary">Add New Post</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

And my file structure:

[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctgvl.png)

I'm really not sure how this happened, it worked then I proceeded to work on this project and then it stopped working at some point. I've played around with different names etc.. always the same problem.

Comment: `php artisan route:clear` then see the list `php artisan route:list`, hope it solve your issue

Comment: this fixed it, thanks very much! any link to where I can learn more about these options, other than playing around with artisan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route has been cached. If you want to clear the cached file, then simply hit :

```
php artisan route:clear
```

You can cache your route again by :

```
php artisan route:cache
```

For more info see the official documentation of **[Route Caching](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#route-caching)**,  **[Optimizing Views](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#optimizing-views)**, **[Environment](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/testing#environment)**

Comment: The route cached method reduces all of your route registrations into a single method call within a cached file, improving the performance of route registration when registering hundreds of routes.